# Equation position equation LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, equations, errors

I'm having trouble with the LaTeX equation numbers. For example, I type:

```latex
        \begin{equation}\label{eq2}
            
           A = \begin{pmatrix}
                 a_{11}x_{1} & a_{12}x_{2} &\space...    & a_{1n}x_{n}
              \\ a_{21}x_{1} & a_{22}x_{2} &\space ...    & a_{2n}x_{n} 
              \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots
              \\ a_{m1}x_{1} & a_{m2}x_{2} & ...  & a_{mn}x_{n} 
            \end{pmatrix}
            
        \end{equation}
```

I expected the number at right but I get:

[image: Incorrect equation number position]

What is the problem with my `equation` block?

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle. My tex file compiled and seemed to work

Comment: no you would have had an error mssage. Overleaf does not highlight errors as much as it could but you would have had a small red x on the blank line and a red circle with an error count in the top bar, and you always have access to the full tex log with the full error mssage

Comment: See [Overleaf view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6wLq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem. I have extra line breaks between `\begin{equation}\label{eq2}` and the start of equation. The correct code:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
           A = \begin{pmatrix}
                 a_{11}x_{1} & a_{12}x_{2} &\space...    & a_{1n}x_{n}
              \\ a_{21}x_{1} & a_{22}x_{2} &\space ...    & a_{2n}x_{n} 
              \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots
              \\ a_{m1}x_{1} & a_{m2}x_{2} & ...  & a_{mn}x_{n} 
            \end{pmatrix}      
        \end{equation}
```

Comment: this is a faq (and a duplicate) so we will probably close as duplicate. In general if you get any error message it is better to ask about the message, not about any pdf output that you get if you scroll past the error, any such pdf is not intended to be usable, just a debugging aid